# How to lock-down input on a Linux machine?

Tags: security, input

We need to put out a web browser to a public place to show informations. I need to lock down all the input interfaces via software methods. So ex.: if someone plugs a USB keyboard to the machine it wouldn't be able to use it.

How to do it under ex.: Ubuntu 12.04? How can I disable USB/other input methods?

Comment: If building a custom kernel is an option, you can only include the drivers you need and disable everything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is typically called Kiosk Mode.

#### Kiosk from scratch

There is a good tutorial over on alandmore's blog titled: [Creating a kiosk with Linux and X11: 2011 edition](http://www.alandmoore.com/blog/2011/11/05/creating-a-kiosk-with-linux-and-x11-2011-edition/).

View this is only a start.

#### LiveCD

Additionally I'd consider using a LiveCD for this type of situation since this will limit any permanent damage one can inflict if they were to game the system.

#### PPL Kiosk

There used to be a project titled: [PPL Kiosk - Kiosk LiveCD for Princeton Public Library](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rLawQQpkLhc8SN5HJthhhZaNuAp6f9lJIV-WAeBdEMY/edit). The project appears to be dead but there is a link to a script: [kioskscript.sh](http://pastebin.com/XEwtCGXq) which will take a Ubuntu system and setup a kiosk mode within it.

#### Kiosk in 10 Easy Steps

This tutorial titled: [Ubuntu 12.04 Kiosk in 10 Easy Steps](http://nexxylove.tumblr.com/post/22690398464/ubuntu-web-kiosk-in-10-easy-steps), doesn't do any hardening of the system but does show how you can configure Ubuntu to only open a web browser after booting up.

#### Going beyond

The above is by no means exhaustive, but should give you a start. I would spend some additional time googling for "Linux Kiosk LiveCD" for additional tips and tricks.